# subsequent save in JPA transaction

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have a service class the injects two JpaRepository classes: organizationRepository and stateRepository.  In the service method I need to perform two transactions:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Status createOrganization(@ResponseBody Organization organization) throws Exception {
    Organization savedOrg = organizationRepository.save(organization);
    int id = savedOrg.getOrgId();

    State state = new State();
    state.setOrgId(id);
    state.setCode("MD");
    State savedState = stateRepository.save(state);
    .
    .
    .
```

This code isn't working and throwing a transaction error on my server.  I also tried a saveAndFlush on the organizationRepository before trying to call the subsequent save for stateRepository.  I realize I could also set the propagation  properties but that didn't fix it either.  The first save transaction always executes, but the second keeps failing.  What can I do to solve?

Comment: I think people will need to take a look on how have you implemented the save() method in both repository classes

Comment: *"...  but the second keeps failing"*  - Error message?  Stacktrace?  You need to provide the relevant info if you want help that goes to the specifics of your problem.